# Port a shadertoy's cloud shader to threejs, how to implement the cloud effect on a box?

Tags: three.js, cloud, glsl, shader, webgl

The shader : https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsfXW8

I'm trying to port this shader to threejs, changed some basic variables, removed the iMouse, and it's basically working. In shadertoy, the cloud is realized based on the screen (plane), after I ported it to threejs, I want to realize the following effect.

1. Create a box.
2. The bound of the cloud is the height/width/depth of the box.
3. The position of the cloud is the position of the box.
4. After adding orbitcontrol in threejs to control the camera, we can achieve the normal rotation and move effect.

In the main function I modified the
`vec3 O = cameraPosition.`

`draw_obj(O, M, uv, 2);` changed to
`draw_obj(O, mat3(viewMatrix[0].xyz, viewMatrix[1].xyz, viewMatrix[2].xyz), uv, 2);`

But the rotation effect is always wrong, and the position of the cloud is not correct, webgl I am a novice, can only try to modify, please help me to point out, I have to do how to realize the effect I want!

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)